# Как в постмане засетить ответ хедера в переменную?

Tags: json, postman, environment-variables

Подскажите пожалуйста как в постмане засетить ответ хедера в переменную?
Вернее не весь ответ, а его часть.
Например получаем в ответе:

1. Date: Mon, 05 Sep 2022 06:59:36 GMT
2. Transfer-Encoding: chunked
3. Content-Type: application/json
4. Value: value1; value2; Value3

И мне нужно записать в переменную Value значение value1

Answer (score 2):

```
var vary = pm.response.headers.get('Value');
var headerArray = vary.split(";");
pm.environment.set("Value_env", headerArray[0]);
```

Вот собственно и ответ, если кому-то интересно)
Берем переменную Value из хедера, указываем разделитель ";" и вытаскиваем первое значение "headerArray[0]"